# Get events from a specific calendar in Swift/SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, calendar, ekeventstore

I'm working on an app in Swift/SwiftUI that displays calendar events from a calendar on the user's device called "All Classes". Details about each event within that calendar should appear in TodayView. To be clear, the app should only display events from the *current day*.

I should note that I'm **very** new to Swift/SwiftUI.

This is what I've tried so far. As expected, the app requests permission to access the calendar, but no events are displayed on-screen. I have not limited the code to searching the "All Classes" calendar simply because I do not know how. Would anyone be able to help? Thanks!

```swift
import SwiftUI
import EventKit
import EventKitUI

let eventStore = EKEventStore()
var events : [EKEvent] = []

struct TodayView: View {
    init() {
        events = getEvents()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                background
                ScrollView (.vertical) {
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(events, id :\.self) { event in
                            Text(event.title)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Today")
        }
    }
}

func getEvents() -> [EKEvent] {
    var eventList : [EKEvent] = []
    eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event) { (granted, error) in
        if granted {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let predicate = eventStore.predicateForEvents(withStart: Date().dayBefore, end: Date().dayAfter, calendars: nil)
                
                let events = eventStore.events(matching: predicate)
                
                for e in events {
                    eventList.append(e)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return eventList
}

extension Date {
    var dayBefore: Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: self)!
    }
    
    var dayAfter : Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: self)!
    }
}
```

Comment: The `eventStore.requestAccess` method is async and you are fetching the events from its completion handler. So the `return eventList` is executed before `requestAccess` could call its completion handler and hence `eventList` is never mutated to contain the fetched events. The linked duplicate clearly explains how to handle asynchronous methods in a synchronous context.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help! Even reading the linked duplicate, I’m still having trouble applying what’s there to my code. Do you have any suggestions?